# Add Account-Level Group to Databricks Workspace using Terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-azure

I use the Databricks SCIM to sync AAD groups to my Databricks account groups. This works fine.

What I am trying to do now is to add an account-level group (that indeed exists under the account) to an existing workspace. The workspace is set-up to allow Identity Federation.

Here are the code snippets I am using (using Terraform version 1.1.6 and azurerm provider version 3.37.0):

```
provider "databricks" {
    host                        = azurerm_databricks_workspace.databricks.workspace_url 
    azure_workspace_resource_id = azurerm_databricks_workspace.databricks.id 
    account_id                  = var.dbrAccount
}

data "databricks_group" "developers" {
  display_name = "my_account_level_group"
}

# Add access to workspace
resource "databricks_mws_permission_assignment" "add_group" {
  workspace_id = <myworkspace_id>
  principal_id = data.databricks_group.developers.id
  permissions  = ["USER"]
}
```

I get the following error from Terraform plan: "cannot find group my_account_level_group".

The account-level group exists. If I manually add this group to the Workspace, and run the code, this Terraform code does work. So it seems like `databricks_group` can only find a group if it is already in a workspace? Although the documentation seems to say otherwise; see e.g. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/mws_permission_assignment.

Need help as how to add an account-level group to a Workspace. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this seems obvious now. To add account level groups, you need to set-up your provider host differently, .i.e.,

```
provider "databricks" {
    host                        = "https://accounts.azuredatabricks.net"
    ...
}
```

Now it can find account level users and groups!

Comment: it's in the top of the documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/group

Comment: Yes, reading is essential :)